# RIA Call fails after one hour exactly with : The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: silverlight, ria

I've done my research and I understand this error message is very vague.  But, I am wondering if someone might give me some insight.  We have a long running RIA call that could take well over an hour or so.

After one hour exactly, we get this error message.

The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

We change the timeout of the RIA call to 4 hours and we still get this error message after an hour.  If we change the timeout to 10 minutes, we get an actual timeout error message after 10 minutes and not a NotFound error message.

Because it happens exactly after one hour - even with different parameters being passed in to the RIA call, I believe it has something to do with a timeout setting somewhere, but I can't put my finger on what would cause a timeout to occur after an hour.

The way I am setting the timeout is in the call to the ria service from the client.

Comment: Do not use RIA to make a call that is that slow. Your client app may have closed in that time, but you want it to resume. Instead start a server process with one call and poll the server for the results with another regular call.

Comment: I know.  That is the plan.  I've already created the achitecture for it.  I am looking for a quick customer fix before we implement the new threading architecture.

Comment: I know there are ways we can increase the timeouts and at least make this functional the way it is.

Comment: In that case, check that you do not have any machine settings overriding your local maximum timeout. 60 Minutes sounds like a default to me.

Comment: I have set all the time outs on the RIA context in client to 4 hours.  Changed values in the web.config.  I am at a loss as to which other settings I can manipulate to change this.

Comment: Try looking for/in machine.config. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think I found the problem and further testing will confirm.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050 - Internet Explorer has a built in recieve time-out of 60 minutes unless it's over ridden by a registry setting.  My initial tests are pointing to this being the problem.

Comment: As per my last comment, this was the problem which I confirmed in my testing.support.microsoft.com/kb/181050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the problem.

Internet Explorer has a built in recieve time-out of 60 minutes unless it's over ridden by a registry setting. My tests have confirmed that this is the problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050